# How to get the highest _id for the collection in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to get highest _id for the Users Collection in Meteor. What is the code for meteor to get highest _id value.

For mongo console we can get it by this command:

```
db.users.find().sort({ _id:-1 }).limit(1).next()._id;
```

How about meteor code for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to get this based on the `_id`.

Try this on the console.

```
var finde = Meteor.users.find({},{limit: 1, sort: {_id: -1}}).fetch();
console.log(isNaN(finde[0]._id)) //this will return true since the id its not a number
```

Lets say you have the `Students Collections.`

and you want to show the highest value inside it.

```
Students.findOne({}, {sort: {idStudent: -1}});
```

where `idStudent` should be a numeric value.

this will return the `highest document` with the idStudent value

Comment: The id is nor numerical nor sequential, how do you expect this to work?

Comment: hmm but didn't you as how to do on the browser? or with server code? thats mongo console

Comment: thank you for answer. the code "db.users.find().sort({ _id:-1 }).limit(1).next()._id" in mongo console will return the highest _id directly. How can we write just one command to get the highest _id. because if we use this code "var finde = Meteor.users.find({},{limit: 1, sort: {_id: -1}})".  "finde" is the collection of users not the highest _id. if it's possible to do this.

Comment: Sim you can return the highest value from an _id, that field contains letters and numbers its impossible

Comment: If I have other collection like Students and I want to generate Id for the students collections when we insert a new student to MongoDB. for example 'IT-001', 'IT-002', 'IT-003'..... so that why I to want you help me to get the highest value of _id in students collection, to know what is the _id for next new student.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is strange. I think that you want the most recent user, in this case you can the `createdAt` field.

If you're looking for numerical and sequentials IDs you can use Mongodb counters, there's a meteor package for this and it's really easy to use: `mrt:mongo-counter@1.1.0`